# Reduce recompilation , sp_execute

Tags: sql, sp-executesql

I'm terrible with the problem on my servers when the problem of recompilation of queries, we report on this server, which are necessary for dynamic queries, researching a solution to this problem I got here.

```
 
   CREATE TABLE YEAR_YEAR (Y INT)
```

`INSERT YEAR_YEAR (Y) VALUES (2011) 
INSERT YEAR_YEAR (Y) VALUES (2012) 
INSERT YEAR_YEAR (Y) VALUES (2013) 
INSERT YEAR_YEAR (Y) VALUES (2014) 

EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql
    N'SELECT * FROM YEAR_YEAR 
    WHERE
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR,Y) IN (@RAEY)
    '
    ,
    N'@RAEY NVARCHAR(100)',
    @RAEY = N'2012,2013';`

When you place a single parameter in the variable works, but when I add the comma does not return me anything, I have done dozens of conversions from trial, replaces ...

Recalling that the data comes from the report, many of them not made ​​by me so then I have to necessarily treat the hard way that is varchar

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

After much research and some trial and error, I arrived at a very satisfactory result, now I will monitor the results of my server.

`EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql
    N'SELECT * FROM YEAR_YEAR 
    WHERE
    (CHARINDEX('','' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,Y) + '','', '','' + REPLACE(@RAEY, '' '', '''') + '','') > 0)
    '
    ,
    N'@RAEY NVARCHAR(100)',
    @RAEY = N'2012,2013';`